# pushing divs content for alert

Tags: css

I have a fixed position navbar, I am trying to push down everything if there is a alert message only. the alert will be fixed also

I tried wrapping my content in a div but it did nothing.

I use foundation 6 I found exactly what I am looking for here http://www.bootply.com/4FSUjc2qej

but it is bootstrap.. but the above code only works if the nav is static. I need the message if shown to stay fixed above the nav. but when clicked to close site slides up to normal.

```
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
    <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Best check yo self, you are looking very good.
</div>

<div id"site">
<nav class="nav">My Nav</nav>
<div>content</div>
</div>


    .alert-info {
      margin-bottom:0;
      position: fixed
    }


.nav {
    min-height: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: visible;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

Comment: You should make 1 container/wrapper div that is `position: fixed;` and put both the alert and nav inside that fixed div instead of making the alert and nav both fixed. Only 1 fixed thing... not 2

Comment: but if I do that it will push the nav down but not the rest of the site

Comment: Yes `fixed` content will sit on top of `static` content... that's how it works. Do you want it so that if someone scrolls half way down your page and gets an alert, the alert pushes the `fixed` nav down AND the `static` content down as well?

Comment: well I when to this one site and some how when there alert show it pushes everything down and when you exit out everything slides back up I have my nav which is 76px high I push down my hero 76px so the site looks as I want.

Comment: You will probably have to do something with javascript where you calculate the height of the alert and the height of the nav and then have the content/hero move down that amount of pixels... then slide back up when it closes. You are not going to be able to get what you want with a fixed nav with pure css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by setting a fixed height for the alert, for instance 40px. Then you can use `transition` for the animation, like this:

```js
function showAlert() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("alert")[0].classList.add("active");
}

function closeAlert() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("alert")[0].classList.remove("active");
}
```

```css
.alert {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  transition: height .2s;
}

.alert.active {
  height: 40px;
}

#site {
  transition: margin-top .2s;
}

.alert.active + #site {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.nav {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  transition: top .2s;
}

.alert.active + #site .nav {
  top: 40px;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 59px
}
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" onclick="closeAlert()">×</button>
  <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Best check yo self, you are looking very good.
</div>

<div id="site">
  <nav class="nav">My Nav</nav>
  <div class="content">
    <button onclick="showAlert()">alert</button>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
</div>
```

So when the alert is displayed, you will have to

1. Set the height of the alert
2. Set the top offset of the site
3. Set the top offset of the nav bar

Comment: This would work but only if you can have a static height alert box. In my experience content that usually goes in alerts is dynamic and can wrap multiple lines so watch out for that. Also, text will wrap differently on different screen resolutions (on a desktop 40px might be plenty of room for an alert, but on a tablet or phone you may need twice that amount of space)